# Laravel belongsTo giving me Query\Builder::save() error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Message`, which has:

```
public function queue() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Queue::class);
}
```

I'm doing this:

```
$queue = new Queue;
$message = App\Message::find(1);
$message->queue()->save($queue);
```

and I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2093:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can have a Queue object as a relation for Model object because AFAIK it works only for Eloquent models. The error tells you that Queue class has no save() method.

Comment: I just found that apparently when using belongsTo, you have to use associate() instead of save() ..

Comment: Good catch @Bravi. And then you probably also have to call `$queue->save()` afterwards. I don't think `associate()` makes a call to the database.

Comment: Yes that is correct! It just updates the model, but does not sync. Thanks!